# Can there be text and additional nodes in XML?

Tags: xml

Is this valid xml?

```
<item>
List of items
<thing> A Thing </thing>
</item>
```

Validators say this is allowed but

A. I have not come across it in any XML documents I have ever seen.

B. While searching the internet for:

> Can an XML Node contain text and other nodes

I could not find any valid responses, nor an example in the specification.

Comment: that's fine, a node can have content and child node(s)

Comment: Yes, this is a well-formed XML. What have you searched so far? What is "*never done*" exactly?

Comment: @potame, I edited my question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XML recommendation, you can have a look at [§3 Logical structures](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-logical-struct).

What you meet here is named ["mixed content"](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#NT-Mixed) (mixing tags and text).

I'm surprised you have never met this before. Think about xhtml: in a paragraph, you are allowed to write down text, `<b>` elements, `<i>` elements, and so on.

A popular document format like Docbook also allows the mix up of tags and text (these are just a few example among several other - you may meet other formats depending on the context you are working on).